# Handling scrolling using iron-scroll-threshold in Polymer 2.0 for scroll-target = document

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to handle scroll threshold events. Using following lines of code

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-scroll-threshold/iron-scroll-threshold.html">  

<dom-module id="documentscroll-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      iron-scroll-threshold {
            display: none;
          }
    </style>
    
    <h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>
    <!-- scroll-target uses the document scroll -->
    <iron-scroll-threshold id="scrollThreshold"
    scroll-target="document"
    lower-threshold="500"
    on-lower-threshold="loadMoreData">
  </iron-scroll-threshold>
    <h4>
       XXXXXXX
      MORE LINES TILL SCROLL IS VISIBLE
    </h4>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class DocumentscrollApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'documentscroll-app'; }
      constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor getting called ");
         super();
        
                    } // End of constructor 
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'documentscroll-app'
          }
        };
      }
      loadMoreData ()
      {
        console.log("Loading more data");
        this.$.scrollThreshold.clearTriggers();

      }
      ready ()
      {
        console.log("Scroll object is READY");
        super.ready();
        this.addEventListener('click', this._onClick);


      }
      _onClick(event) {
       console.log("Click getting called");
     }

    }

    window.customElements.define(DocumentscrollApp.is, DocumentscrollApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

The on-lower-threshold is not getting invoked at all. I have used document as  scroll-target. And the component is getting created as expected. Can see messages for "Click" as well.
Ideally on reaching the threshold the call back should get invoked. I am not seeing this getting invoked even once. Note :To generate scroll I have added more text content than the one shown in the example.

Comment: Try `ironScrollTheshold.clearTriggers();` instead `this.$.scrollThreshold.clearTriggers();`  And check is it firing `loadMoreData ` at start ? .

Comment: Thanks for the revert. Tried the changes suggested they don't seem to work. The call back is not getting triggered even once. Do let me know if you want any further information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working sample for `iron-scroll-threshold` ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-scroll-threshold/iron-scroll-threshold.html">
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <test-component></test-component>
  <dom-module id="test-component">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }
      iron-scroll-threshold {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
    <iron-ajax auto url= "{{url}}"  last-response="{{response}}"></iron-ajax>
   <iron-scroll-threshold id="mytras" on-lower-threshold="loadMoreData" lower-threshold="100" scroll-target="document">
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{response.results}}">
     <span>&nbsp; [[index]] :  [[item.name.first]] [[item.name.last]]</span><br/><br/><br/>
   </template>  
   </iron-scroll-threshold>
  </template>
  <script>
    class MyTest extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'test-component'; }
      static get properties() { return { 
        people:{
          type:Number,
          value:20
        }       
     }};
    static get observers() { return ['_url(people)']}
   _url(p){
      console.log(p);
      this.url = "https://randomuser.me/api?results=" + p;
      setTimeout(()=> {
                this.$.mytras.clearTriggers();
      },900)
   }

   loadMoreData (){
      console.log("God call me for every scroll");
      this.people += 10;                
   }
 }
customElements.define(MyTest.is, MyTest);
</script>
</dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example code. 
I used the same one except the dom name. 
Still no event is getting fired however 
I am able to see the text list that's getting retrieved.
Also getting following error: "Uncaught TypeError: this.$.mytras.clearTriggers is not a function"

Comment: Unable to find a suitable version for polymer, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) polymer#~1.0.3 which resolved to 1.0.9 and is required by iron-scroll-threshold#1.0.2
    2) polymer#^2.0.0 which resolved to 2.3.1 and is required by scrollfinal
    3) polymer#1.9 - 2 which resolved to 2.3.1 and is required by iron-ajax#2.0.8

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer 2.3.1

Comment: I tested and working at my local host. You need to download proper version of components. For this, if you use polymer ^2.0 then choose always most recent version  (over 2.00) versions when you met with above message

Comment: Apologies for the troubling you. Here is the link to my code [link] (https://codepen.io/sachindn/pen/baxvmb) can you please take a look? Also this.$.mytras.clearTriggers() is throwing undefined error.

Comment: I think `iron-scroll-threshold` componnent not installed. Be sure it's working as I tested. Just be sure the components are installed that listed in head tag. Even try to install at a new directory all from _> polymer init. (Sorry i can connect through mobile phone. That's why I couldn't edit your codepen code)

Comment: I don't know why but the same code works on my localhost. (with polymer serve) But not working at `codepen`