# Polymer: How to use iron-scroll-threshold in Polymer 2

Tags: polymer

I want to use iron-scroll-threshold element, to load more data when i scroll, but an example that i found at webcomponents seems not to work.
It doesnt return anything at console.This is my code:

```
<iron-scroll-threshold lower-threshold="400" on-lower-threshold="loadMoreData" id="threshold">
  <iron-list scroll-target="threshold" items="[[ajaxResponse]]" as="item">
    <template>
      <div>[[item.name]]</div>
    </template>
  </iron-list>
</iron-scroll-threshold>

my function: loadMoreData() { 
    console.log("Inside ..."); 

    asyncStuff(function done() { 
        ironScrollTheshold.clearTriggers(); 
    }
);
```

Comment: it returns me an error when i put function code in same comment

Comment: Accepted, thanks - do you know answer on this question ??

Comment: @Azim check this out there also a demo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249791/handling-scrolling-using-iron-scroll-threshold-in-polymer-2-0-for-scroll-target/48267328#48267328

Comment: Hakan it returns me this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.$.mytras.clearTriggers is not a function
    at setTimeout (my-view1.html:54)

Comment: iron-threshold seems to be a component with a lot of bugs. 
https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-scroll-threshold/issues/23
I went with implementing my own function to detect lower threshold, and a lot of people seems to think that is the way to go

Comment: where could i see your implementation of this element ?

Comment: I did not implement this element. Since this element is broken, I instead  used a event listener that will listen to document scroll event, calculate the distance from the bottom, and call function depending on the distance.

Comment: @Azrim, its work without problem at my own webapp:  https://jobijoy.com . You may check it out. When I try to run the same code at wer servers, like codepen or here's code editor. It does not work. For this. try to instan clean polymer into a new directory. And Install bower dependencies (at this link : https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/qpQmwd) and test with polymer serve. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Iron-threshold seems to have a lot of problems as described here:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-scroll-threshold/issues/23

I suggest not using it and just implement a scroll event listener of your own kind of like this:

```
    const lowerThreshold = 500
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
      var body = document.body // For Chrome, Safari and Opera
      var html = document.documentElement // Firefox and IE
      var documentHeight = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight )
      var windowHeight = window.innerHeight
      var bodyScrollBottom = documentHeight - windowHeight - body.scrollTop
      var htmlScrollBottom = documentHeight - windowHeight - html.scrollTop

      //to take in account for difference browsers
      if( bodyScrollBottom < lowerThreshold ){
        //below the threshold. Do something
        //for Chrome, Safari and Opera
      }else if( htmlScrollBottom < lowerThreshold){
        //below thre threshold. Do something
        //for Firefox and IE
      }
    })
```